# spin-fiat not starting during hal config apply: services.front50.baseUrl

Tags: spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

Hal Version

```
root@9d4ea3d3c90e:/workdir# hal --version
0.43.0-180317140630
```

Applying config with hal

```
root@9d4ea3d3c90e:/workdir# hal deploy apply
+ Get current deployment
  Success
+ Prep deployment
  Success
Problems in default.provider.kubernetes.sandbox-spinnaker:
- WARNING Field KubernetesAccount.kinds not supported for Spinnaker
  version 1.6.0: Configuring kind caching behavior is not supported yet.
? Use at least 1.7.0 (It may not have been released yet).

- WARNING Field KubernetesAccount.omitKinds not supported for
  Spinnaker version 1.6.0: Configuring kind caching behavior is not supported
  yet.
? Use at least 1.7.0 (It may not have been released yet).

+ Preparation complete... deploying Spinnaker
+ Get current deployment
  Success
+ Apply deployment
  Success
+ Run `hal deploy connect` to connect to Spinnaker.
```

Status of pods

```
$ kubectl get pods
NAME                               READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
spin-clouddriver-f54b887f-hmnsx    1/1       Running            0          19h
spin-deck-598f8df868-6jlhl         1/1       Running            0          19h
spin-echo-84d9b7d679-whv6n         1/1       Running            0          19h
spin-fiat-78b899d45d-dk767         0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   4          3m
spin-front50-65d476986f-hgnsq      1/1       Running            0          19h
spin-gate-67b6955476-b7dhj         1/1       Running            0          19h
spin-igor-56f7f9b85f-rj7fl         1/1       Running            0          19h
spin-orca-6c4f48cf49-5knlc         1/1       Running            0          19h
spin-redis-69b6cc4c46-vmfhr        1/1       Running            0          5d
```

Log message from spin-fiat

```
$ kubectl logs spin-fiat-78b899d45d-dk767
...
2018-03-21 17:16:10.472 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : [] Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourcesConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'services.front50.baseUrl' in value "${services.front50.baseUrl}"
```

I'm not sure why spin-fiat is not starting.

Any tips on how to troubleshoot appreciated.

Comment: what was your hal config back then?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed in [PR#1511](https://github.com/spinnaker/spinnaker/pull/1511)

I suggest you upgrade your Spinnaker to version 1.20.X. That version uses the new Kubernetes V2 provider. Also the FIAT issue is gone. You must install or upgrade halyard for this new Spinnaker Release.

1. Upgrade Halyard
2. Upgrade Spinnaker to version 1.20.X